# 'rm' (delete) thousands of files selectively

Tags: files, filesystem, delete, rm

I created a cache system in my web server which stores the HTML files of each webpage, instead of dynamic producing them. As a consequence, I have 50,000+ files within a directory in a Linux server. They are labelled: `section1-xxx.html`, `section2-xxx.html`, and so on.

Now, I have problems when I try to selectively delete some of them. When I run `rm section1-*.html`, the shell warns me that they are too many files. Any tip to manage to delete them?

Answer (score 9):

Either

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'section1-*.html' -delete
```

(test it first with `-print` in place of `-delete`) or

```
printf '%s\0' ./section1-*.html | xargs -r0 rm
```

(test it first with `echo` in place of `rm`)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `section*-*.html` so they can continue to delete the `section2*` and so on files as well?

Comment: @Terrance The OP wants the effect that running `rm section1-*.html` would have if the shell were able to pass such a long argument list to an external command.

Comment: @Terrance I see what you mean. I *think* they mentioned that to clarify that there were other files in the directory that should *not* be deleted, or perhaps because they may sometimes want to delete files associated with a specific other section. But it may be that they really do want to delete all the sections, and had tried matching just the section 1 files with the hope that the argument list would be short enough for the command to succeed.

Comment: @EliahKagan hopefully once the OP understands what the issue is and how to address it, they can decide themselves how "wild" they want to go with the wildcard matching.

Comment: @EliahKagan That makes sense and I see what you mean.  Sometimes trying to think logically this early in the morning for me hurts my brain.  =)

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah, it didn't work for the 411.  It worked for all the others though.